# Python 3 encode error

Tags: python, arrays, string, encoding, cp1252

Recently I encountered the following problem:

I have an array of strings:

`name in ['Mueller', 'Meier', 'Schulze', 'Schmidt']`

I face problems with its encoding in `Python 3`:

```
name.encode('cp1252')
```

Here is the full snippet:

```
 target_name = [name.encode('cp1252')
                         for name in
                         ['Mueller', 'Meier', 'Schulze', 'Schmidt']]
     assert_array_equal(arr['surname'],
                        target_name)
```

And here is the point where I also get the error. The error states:

> Fail in test..... dtype='<|S7>'

I've been searching for a solution for some time, what I found so far is the need of changing the encoding. I applied:

```
name = np.char.encode('cp1252')
```

However I get another type of error with it.

Could someone help me with the error tracking?

Comment: Is indentation OK?

Comment: Yes, totally fine, it looks only like this here, but indentation is good otherwise :)

Comment: What is `arr['surname']`? Could we have it?

Comment: It seems like problem is not about encoding. Is `assert_array_equal` from numpy?

Comment: Exactly, assert_array_equal is from numpy.

Here is the description :) 

self.arr = XRecArray.empty((4), dtype=dtype)
...
        self.arr.surname[:4] = [name.encode('cp1252')
                                for name in
                                ['Mueller', 'Meier', 'Schulze', 'Schmidt']]

XRecArray is an array created for the purpose of the program and can be seen as a black-box :)